# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'solution.models.model'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having poblem with Session. 
Error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.String' to type 'Boighor.Models.KhachHang'.'

But I don't know why it can not cast to object. 
My code:

```
<div>
<h2 class="text-center">Info Order</h2>
@{ KhachHang customer = (KhachHang)HttpContext.Current.Session["TaiKhoan"]; }
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Info</th>
            <th scope="col">Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Full name:</td>
            <td>@customer.HoTen</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td>@customer.DiachiKH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td>@customer.DienThoaiKH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Order date:</td>
            <td>@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Delivery date:</td>
            <td><input type="date" name="NgayGiao" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm order</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET Core MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
(KhachHang)HttpContext.Current.Session["TaiKhoan"];
```

you are casting whatever is in session under the `TaiKhoan` key to the type `KhachHang`.
Seems, however, that what you have there is not of the `KhachHang` but rather - it's a string.

Q: How to resolve the issue?

A: Find all places in your code where you **add** a value to session container, under the `TaiKhoan` key. There possibly are multiple places in your code that do this. One (or many) of this code snippets add a string.

Q: What else is wrong with my code?

A: You should not be initializing variables in your view, that's against MVC. This line of code

```
@{ KhachHang customer = (KhachHang)HttpContext.Current.Session["TaiKhoan"]; }
```

should be in your controller/action, not in the view. The view should have a model type and this variable should be passed to the view by the controller in a model instance.